# Saving blob video with php

Tags: php, file, video, blob

I am trying to send a buffered video to save it as a file on my server.
Always the file is empty.

My js get the url "blob:https://..." and sends to the php that receive it.

```
$file = file_get_contents(url);
file_put_contents($video_url_mp4."helloWorld.webm",$file);
```

I tried send the video as canvas and i only get one frame.
suggest please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blob url is only usable in the browser that created it. So you cant use it on your server or copy and paste it into another browser or send the link to your friend etc.
What you need to do is get the blob that url was created from and use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and upload that to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I get a file with the content as string on my php but this is not in a video format.

my js:

```
var myFile = new File(video.src);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data', myFile);
```

and my php:

```
$f = $_POST['data'];
$decode = base64_decode(preg_replace('/^data\:image\/webp\;base64\,/', '', $f));
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Is `video.src` a data url or a blob url?